# Simple.Data Many-to-many Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many, simple.data

So I'm working through a simplified example of my hoped-for database that has the following tables:

```
Contractors: Id, ContractorName
Types: Id, TypeName
CoverageZips: ContractorId, Zip
TypesForContractors: ContractorId, TypeId
```

where contractors can have many zips and types and types and zips can have many contractors (many-to-many).

I'm trying to:

1. do a search for contractors in a certain zip code
2. then load the types for those contractors.

The SQL for the first part would probably look like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Contractors WHERE Id IN
(SELECT ContractorId FROM dbo.CoverageZips WHERE Zip = 12345)
```

Here's what I have for the first part in Simple.Data. It's working, but I feel like I'm missing some of the beauty of Simple.Data...

```
List<int> contractorIds = new List<int>();
foreach(var coverage in _db.CoverageZips.FindAllByZip(zip)) {
    contractorIds.Add((int)coverage.ContractorId);
}
var contractors = new List<dynamic>();
if (contractorIds.Count > 0) {
    contractors = _db.Contractors.FindAllById(contractorIds).ToList<dynamic>();
}
return contractors;
```

That's working ok until I try part 2:

```
public dynamic GetAllForZip(int zip) {
    List<int> contractorIds = new List<int>();
    foreach(var coverage in _db.CoverageZips.FindAllByZip(zip)) {
        contractorIds.Add((int)coverage.ContractorId);
    }
    var contractors = new List<dynamic>();
    if (contractorIds.Count > 0) {
        contractors = _db.Contractors.FindAllById(contractorIds).ToList<dynamic>();
    }
    foreach (var contractor in contractors) {
        // Exception occurs here on second iteration
        // even though the second contractor was originally in the contractors variable
        contractor.types = GetTypesForContractor((int)contractor.Id);
    }
    return contractors;
}

public dynamic GetTypesForContractor(int id) {
    var types = new List<dynamic>();
    if (id > 0) {
        List<int> typeIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (var typeForContractor in _db.TypesForContractor.FindAllByContractorId(id)) {
            typeIds.Add((int)typeForContractor.TypeId);
        }

        if (typeIds.Count > 0) {
            types = _db.ContractorTypes.FindAllById(typeIds).ToList<dynamic>();
        }
    }
    return types;
}
```

I set a breakpoint and everything works ok for the first iteration showing , but is failing on the second with the following exception:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

tl;dr

I'm not sure how to properly use many-to-many relationships with Simple.Data and something weird is happening when I try my method more than once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what's happening with that exception and will investigate today.

You are missing some beauty, though. Assuming you have referential integrity configured on your database (which of course you do ;)), your methods can be written thus:

```
public dynamic GetAllForZip(int zip) {
    var contractors = _db.Contractors
        .FindAll(_db.Contractors.ContractorZips.Zip == zip)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var contractor in contractors) {
        contractor.Types = GetTypesForContractor((int)contractor.Id);
    }
    return contractors;
}

public dynamic GetTypesForContractor(int id) {
    return _db.ContractorTypes
        .FindAll(_db.ContractorTypes.TypesForContractor.ContractorId == id)
        .ToList();
}
```

Update!

As of 1.0.0-beta3, eager-loading across many-to-many joins is supported, so now you can do this:

```
public dynamic GetAllForZip(int zip) {
    return _db.Contractors
        .FindAll(_db.Contractors.ContractorZips.Zip == zip)
        .With(_db.Contractors.TypesForContractor.ContractorTypes.As("Types"))
        .ToList();
}
```

And that executes as a single SQL select to make your DBA happy like rainbow kittens.

Comment: Developers are border-line spoiled; a response from the developer of the library?! Awesome. I figured there was a pretty way to do it, but I can't believe just how beautiful that is. Your solution works perfectly, but I'm still getting the exception when more than one record is retrieved. As I'm new to StackOverflow, is there some etiquette for me to post more detailed information to try and zoom in on the issue?

Comment: If you're still having a problem, best place to dig into it is http://github.com/markrendle/simple.data/issues

Comment: Also, please make sure you're using the latest 1.0.0-beta release by installing with the -pre flag on the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've updated to 1.0.0-beta3 and I'm having the same issue. I've started an issue here: https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues/167 Thanks again for your awesome library and help!